# SwiftUI - Hide/Collapse section on scroll

Tags: animation, scrollview, swiftui

I've been searching for a way to replicate the scroll animation that Airbnb and many other's do with a top portion of the view collapsing/hiding on scroll and reappearing immediately when the user starts scrolling up again. Notice how the "Dates" and "Guest" button fades transparent upon scrolling in the attached image.

[image: AirBnB]

Below I've attached a simple view that I just threw together. I've tried including the area I want to collapse both inside and outside of the scrollview. I would guess that it would need to be outside of the scrollview since it would animate independently to the where you are inside of the scroll area.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HideScrollView: View {
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        HStack {
            Text("Hide Me")
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal) .frame(height: 60) .background(Color.red) .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        ForEach(0 ..< 20) { item in
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Content Items")
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.horizontal) .frame(height: 40)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 9):

As there is no delegates for scrollView like didScroll or any, there are two ways to achieve the desired result.

#1 You should implement DragGesture gesture, which is not preferred way to do, because gesture won't be called simultaneously.

```
.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ transition in
    if transition.translation.height > 0{
        withAnimation{
            self.viewIsShown = true
        }
    } else {
        withAnimation{
            self.viewIsShown = false
        }
    }
})
)
```

#2 Preferred way: according to [Martin's tutorial](https://martinmitrevski.com/2020/04/17/collapsing-top-bar-animation-with-swiftui/), you should use `GeometryReader` inside `ScrollView` as first child, and this giving you possibility to get exact position of element inside `GeometryReader`, like this:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.clear.preference(key: OffsetKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in:.global).minY).frame(height: 0)
   }
//Your scrollable content here
}
```

Add your preference key, which conforms to PreferenceKey protocol:

```
struct OffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}
```

Read values which are set in preference key, to do so add `.onPreferenceChange(OffsetKey.self)` to ScrollView or any it's parent view.

You should have `@State` wrapper for both `initialOffest` and `offset`.

```
.onPreferenceChange(OffsetKey.self) {
    if self.initialOffset == nil || self.initialOffset == 0 {
        self.initialOffset = $0
        //setting initialOffest when view first appeared.
    }
    self.offset = $0
    
}
```

Checking difference between `initialOffset` and `offset` will tell you the scroll state of your view. If `initialOffset` is higher than `offset` then your view is scrolled down, and you should hide the view you wish.

Accordingly to your code posted in question, it should look like this:

```
struct HideScrollView: View {
    
    @State var initialOffset: CGFloat?
    @State var offset: CGFloat?
    @State var viewIsShown: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            HStack {
                Text("Hide Me")
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.horizontal) .frame(height: 60) .background(Color.red) .foregroundColor(Color.white).opacity(self.viewIsShown ? 1 : 0)
            
            ScrollView {
                
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.preference(key: OffsetKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)
                        .frame(height: 0)
                }
                
                ForEach(0 ..< 20) { item in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Content Items")
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.horizontal) .frame(height: 40)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onPreferenceChange(OffsetKey.self) {
            if self.initialOffset == nil || self.initialOffset == 0 {
                self.initialOffset = $0
            }
            
            self.offset = $0
            
            guard let initialOffset = self.initialOffset,
                let offset = self.offset else {
                return
            }
            
                
                if(initialOffset > offset){
                    self.viewIsShown = false
                    print("hide")
                } else {
                    self.viewIsShown = true
                    print("show")
                }
            
        
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct OffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?,
                       nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question, doing this  . I See in the preview that when Text Hides. It still leaves the frame gap  ( taken space ) In the view. I will like the scrolling content to take ( fill the empty space where the text was ) as I scroll down... how can do this ???

Comment: adding `GeometryReader` to a `List` will show an empty row even if the height of the reader is zero

Comment: I may be wrong, but in the last Code snipped under .onPreferenceChange(OffsetKey.self) -> if(initialOffset > offset) , I think you swapped self.viewIsShown = false, it should be true then false, not the opposite since you have the State var true by default.